# LogMeIn: does this service put a web server on the server machine, or does all data pass through the LogMeIn servers?

Tags: remote-desktop

LogMeIn: does this service put a web server on the server machine, or does all data pass through the LogMeIn servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LogMeIn uses their servers as a proxy. This is needed to ensure that traffic between the local and remote systems are able to traverse NAT firewalls correctly.